# How do I clear a session or logout using the LinkedIn REST API

Tags: node.js, express, session, linkedin-api

I'm currently writing a program in which multiple accounts need to be authenticated through the LinkedIn REST API. This needs to be done in fairly quick succession as it's quite common to have to re-connect multiple accounts at once due to LinkedIn's fairly short-lived tokens.

The issue is that after authenticating a single account I then have to wait ~10 minutes for the session to expire before authenticating a new user. When the API is called (liLogin) it will automatically log the user in as part of the existing session.

I believe this is an intentional feature of the API as you can see mentioned in Step 5 of [The Authorization Code Flow Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin/context).

Other things to note. I've tried adding a random string as a query on the callback URL which was mentioned in another thread. I've also noticed the Android SDK has a logout function but can't seem to locate anything for this within the REST API.

I've pasted the part of my code that handles this below in-case this helps in anyway.

```
// Login
const liLogin = async (req, res) => {
    const URL = `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?client_id=${config.li.id}&redirect_uri=${config.li.redirectUri}&response_type=code&state=PostSchedulerCapture321&scope=r_liteprofile%20r_emailaddress%20w_member_social`;
    res.redirect(URL);
};

// Exchange temp token for access_token
const liGetUser = (req, res) => {
    let token = req.query.code;
    axios.get(`https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken`, {
        params: {
            "grant_type": "authorization_code",
            "code": token,
            "redirect_uri": config.li.redirectUri,
            "client_id": config.li.id,
            "client_secret": config.li.secret
        }
    })
    .then(result => {
        return result.data.access_token;
    })
    .then(access_token => {
        axios.get('https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me', {
            'headers': {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${access_token}`
            }
        })
        .then(result => {
            res.send(result.data)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        err = {...err.config.headers, ...err.response.data};
        console.log(err);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In-case anyone comes across this you can simply redirect the browser to the logout URL (https://linkedin.com/m/logout) and then use setTimeout to close the window after a few seconds.

Not an ideal solution but it works.

Comment: If not the ideal solution, has anyone ever found an actual solution to this?